# rsync: Compare 2 directories, copy and rename different files instead of overwriting target

Tags: linux, rsync, backup, file-comparison

I can't find a solution to do the following with rsync on Linux:

- Compare two folders
- When found two identical files on the same root position on both source tree and target tree, with same name, but different timestamp or size:
- Instead of updating the target file (less size or older timestamp) with the source on (newer or bigger size), either by appending the missing chunks to the content (using -u), or replacing the Whole file (using -W), I'd like to have it: copying it, to the same tree position, with a name prefix or suffix.

There has been a [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/506005/compare-2-directories-and-copy-differences-in-a-3rd-directory) to avoid losing the older file if overridden, by copying them into a third folder, but I think copying them to the same place on target, and renaming them, keeping the old one there too, would be of a better context by keeping the new files locations.

Here is how I want it to work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're wanting to do versioning of files. This was discussed in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146703/use-rsync-for-backup-without-overwrite), with the exception that you're wanting to work on an entire directory. It's pretty easy to do (taken from @Sridhar-Sarnobat's answer):

```
rsync -ab --suffix=`date +'.%F_%H-%M-%S'` ${SRC}/ ${DEST}
```

Comment: Thank you @ErikF for pointing me out to that answer.  I tried this code:    rsync -zrvt --progress --backup --suffix=`date +'.%F_%H-%M'`
/home/office1/Music/rsync-test1/target/ /home/office1/Music/rsync-test1/source    but it did nothing. However, I added a figure to my question, so it becomes more clearer. Please see why the code didn't work?

Comment: Did you accidentally swap target and source? Also, I did some testing and found that the file in the destination is the one that's renamed, not the file from the source (for example updating `1.txt` in the source will make it the new `1.txt`, and the matching file in the destination becomes `1.txt.2017-12-30_22-22-50`): this doesn't quite match what you were looking for in the original question, and actually wasn't what I had expected!

Comment: This code needs to be changed to make the incremental suffix value (as my example) - or just the time-stamp, as in the example code - to do that to the "copied source file" only, leaving the destination file intact. Thanks for your input!